# How to use key for @cacheable annotation on a method which doesn't have a method parameter

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache, spring-cache

I have a methods for caching, and a method for cache eviction I want to use a cache key attribute to access cache, How do I force or lock someone calling this method to use same key.

I tried something like this but, It didn't seem right. method parameter (cachekey) can be passed as any value desired by the caller.

```
@Cacheable(value = "cacheNamex" , key ="#cachekey") 
    public   List  someCachableMethod(String cacheKey ) {
        List someList = someJdbctemplet.query(SOME_QUERY, someRowMapperObj);
        System.out.println(" data Returned from method");
        return someList;
    }
@CacheEvict((value = "cacheNamex" , key ="#cachekey") 
    public void someCacheEvictMethod(String cacheKey ){
           System.out.println("cache eviction called");
           System.out.println(" Expecting cache, cachex is cleared ");  }
```

Comment: If the method has no parameter, then why do you need more than a single fixed key?

Comment: same cache is used by different cacheable methods  so I want  to uniquely identify each cacheable method with a key.

Comment: @cacheEvict annotation has some problems, it didn't work as expected. I had to create an instance for my cache and evict instead of using annotations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your method don't have any parameter just put the same method name as key and use it to Evict:

```
@Cacheable(value = "cacheNamex" , key ="'someCachableMethod'")
 public   List  someCachableMethod() {
 }
 @CacheEvict((value = "cacheNamex" , key ="'someCachableMethod'") 
 public void someCacheEvictMethod(){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you method does not have parameter you can use the annotation with no key value, if you want more information about this topic please refer to http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-default-key in the spring documentation..

Comment: Cristian,  I have only single cache defined in my application so to access precisely my cache data for a particular method I need to use a key to make sure I'm evicting same cache data